# How many bits of codification G.711 sends in each datagrama?

Tags: voip

I am learning about codecs,and I get this question that I didnt understood  the  answers.
Assuming CODEC G.711 where each datagram carries 20ms of voice, indicate:
3) [E] How many bytes of G.711 encoding does each datagram carry?
A- 20ms/8*0,02=160

4) What is the byte size of each frame carrying G.711 on an Ethernet network?
Note: The dimensions (in bytes) of the base headers of some of the protocols that might be involved in the communication: Ethernet = 18, IP = 20, TCP = 20, UDP = 8, ICMP = 8, RTP = 12
A-18+20+8+12+160=218

I didnt get this math..

Answer (score 0):

g711 codecs pure bandwidth(codec only) is 64kbit, exact

g711 packet length can be 10,20(default),30.. upto 150ms.

So for default settings you have 20ms packet(50 packet/sec) at 64kbit = 160Bytes without udp packet header

Full length of g711(default 20ms) packet is

**TPS   =   18 bytes+20 bytes+8 bytes+12 bytes+160 bytes**

You have 160 bytes of raw data, first you make it rtp packet(timestamp mostly), see packet size at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol 
RTP required fore reorder when you get two packet in different order(sometimes happens).

Now you have rtp, BUT it not suitable for send, need know where to send,  need address and port. For port part you use UDP packet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

For address you use IP packet  header, without address it not go destination machine
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol

Okay, now you have packet. But you still need actually send it. For send you use some hardware level protocol, in this case it is ETHERNET. Ethernet have mac address, which allow fast switching without parse of IP. That is last 18 bytes
https://scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=ajsr.2017.110.115

In some cases you can prefer TCP(when you have packet loss or complex networking), in this case you not use UDP, use TCP  **instead** of it. So you swap 8bytes UDP for 20 bytes TCP.